# How to know what 'this' keyword refers to when reading any codes?

Tags: android, this, keyword

I'm learning Android. I've known about **this** keyword when creating a constructor. However, it is still very confusing for me to know exactly what **this** refers to in other situations.

Specifically, when reading code examples, in some methods, they passed in **this** as a parameter, and I dont know what **this** means so I cannot replicate the code for later uses.

Please intruct me what I should do to find out the reference by 'this' when reading any code or giving parameter as 'this'.

Thank you very much!

See this for an example:

```
    public class Example_5 extends AppCompatActivity {

    ListView lv5;
    List<Country> countries;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_example_5);

        lv5 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lv5);

        countries = new ArrayList<>();
        countries.add(new Country("Vietnam", "Việt Nam", R.drawable.flag_vi));
        countries.add(new Country("Laos", "Lào", R.drawable.flag_fr));
        countries.add(new Country("Japan", "Nhật Bản", R.drawable.flag_jp));
        countries.add(new Country("USA", "Mỹ", R.drawable.flag_us));


        CountryAdapter3 adapter3 = new CountryAdapter3(this, countries, R.layout.item_layout_3);
        lv5.setAdapter(adapter3);


    }


}
```

Comment: Learn basic Java first then get started on Android later
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/thiskey.html

Comment: `Within an instance method or a constructor, this is a reference to the current object — the object whose method or constructor is being called. You can refer to any member of the current object from within an instance method or a constructor by using this.`  - A copy from docs for lazy one.

Comment: I've read this already, and it does not help in finding the use in real situation. 
What I want to know is, is there any way we can know what a 'this' keyword is pointing to any real object or instance as I cannot Ctrl+ click on it!

Answer (score 0):

Do like this:

```
Toast.makeText(this, this.getClass().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

you will see the class name

Comment: Thanks. I will try your method, we only know it when running apps. Is there any faster way when we just read the source and know what it is about? I'm really appreciated.